# Crazy? Generate unusable electricity

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I know that sounds crazy, but today I am wondering if there is a way to generate a current that is unusable by almost all electric/electronic devices?

The idea would be to generate that current and have only a special device being able to use it.
The solution I am looking for should work regardless of the voltage and generated current.

Edit 1:

My gut feeling tells me that if current is flowing, any resistor could be able to use the current. However, one approach that could work in my case is to just detect when another device is using the power source and cut the juice.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the rules. You want to generate electricity that 'almost all' devices cannot use? Well 'almost all' devices cannot use wireless power transfer, so does that count?

Comment: If you used magnetism in stead of electricity, very few devices could use such a circuit, but they tend to be quite leaky. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit

Answer (score 1):

Generate your current at very high frequency. Almost all devices could not use it unless they were tuned to that (high) frequency or had high speed diode rectification. The downside is that the power cables (unless it is coax) would radiate horribly and be illegal.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that *any* current/voltage could be used by a resistor as a heater. This is rather short as an answer...  so here are some relevant equations

$$power = VI $$

and if the resistor behaves normally (ohmically)

$$power = I^2R $$

where $I$ is current, $R$ resistance (and $V$ voltage).

Answer (score 0):

What about a very low frequency rectangular voltage, say $1$ Hz or less, alternating from $0$ to $V_{max}$. Many devices would reset each second and thus be effectively unable to function. Your device however has a large enough capacitor or other storage medium to deal with the $0$ V time intervals.